# Dynamically creating ASP.NET Web User Control contain AJAX Extender is throwing error "Extender controls may not be registered after PreRender"

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to dynamically add a web user control that contains an AJAX collapsible panel with a Gridview inside the panel when a user clicks on a button. I am able to add a single instance of the user control but when I add additional user controls it throws the following error:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Extender controls
>   may not be registered after PreRender.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I am new to ASP.NET Development and the method I am using to handle postbacks is to store the user controls in a list and add them again on prerender method call. I am not sure what to do or if I am handling the creation of the user controls correctly. Any advice is appreciated.

Here is the back end code:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private IList<Control> _persistedControls;
    private const string PersistedControlsSessionKey = "thispage_persistedcontrols";

static int count = 1;
private IList<Control> PersistedControls()
{
    if (_persistedControls == null)
    {
        if (Session[PersistedControlsSessionKey] == null)
            Session[PersistedControlsSessionKey] = new List<Control>();
        _persistedControls = Session[PersistedControlsSessionKey] as IList<Control>;
    }
    return _persistedControls;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PersistedControls();
}

protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    IList<Control> controlsToGenerate = PersistedControls();

    // regenerate dynamically created controls
    foreach (var control in controlsToGenerate)
    {
        MasterPanel.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = LoadControl("~/WebUserControl/UseCaseSetupUserControl.ascx");
    control.ID = "uc" + count++.ToString();
    MasterPanel.Controls.Add(control);
    _persistedControls.Add(control);
    MasterPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    _persistedControls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));  
}
```

}

Here is the ASPX Code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>    
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />
            <asp:Panel ID="MasterPanel" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>    
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?  I have a TabContainer with each tab containing a user control.  The user controls are using CollapsiblePanelExtender's.  When I try to recreate the tabs OnInit I get the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Create your controls as early as possible in the Page life cycle.

Since you have the `PersistedControls` on load, that is where you should add them to the controls collection. The best place to add controls in `Init`.

If you really can't do that then use `Load`.

If this must be done on an event, then you can add the control there for the first time, but persist it and remember to add it back on **Init or Load** from the next postback onwards.

If you add controls after `PreRender` they cannot add any of their data to the `ViewState`. SaveViewState occurs just before `PreRender`. A lot of controls rely heavily on the `ViewState` to function properly. The exception is simply telling you that you should add your control earlier on in the Page lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice, I tried OnInit, OnLoad, PageLoad, OnPreInit, and OnPreLoad with no success I still get the same error.